# MySQL drop foreign key too slow?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, key, innodb

Dropping a foreign key on a table with 215k+ (with alter table) records seems to take a long time (17+ minutes). Is it possible to somehow speed up the process? 
SQL: ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_GRID_STORE`;

It is a magento upgrade that takes ages

Comment: Solid state drive should do it, lol

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using [InnoDB Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/index.html)  (and by default, in MySQL 5.0 and 5.1 you are not), removing an index require rebuilding the whole table.

If you can't upgrade MySQL, you should either look at online-schema-change (involving transfering all of the data to a new table without the index) or stop the site, minimize any I/O activity and wait the operation to complete.

Comment: Specifically it says in the [MySQL 5.5 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html):

"In MySQL 5.5 and higher, or in MySQL 5.1 with the InnoDB Plugin,
creating and dropping secondary indexes does not copy the contents 
of the entire table, making this operation much more efficient than
with prior releases."